# Proving that $H'_0=\frac{\pi^2}6$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation, harmonic-numbers

I was taking the derivative of $$H_x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac x{k(k+x)}$$ when I found out that $$H_0'=\frac{\pi^2}6$$Simply taking the derivative and plugging $x=0$ is not intuitive to me. What are other ways to prove that $H'_0=\frac{\pi^2}6$?

Comment: I do not get your question, are you saying that taking $H'_x$ at $x=0$ is not an intuitive way to compute $H'_0$?

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes. Taking the derivative is pretty easy which makes this method boring.

Comment: @Kamal Saleh If you are looking for the derivative of an expression, why not simply take it (even if it is boring)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not like to take the term-by-term derivative of the series, you can come back to the definition of derivative $H'_0 = \lim_{x\to 0} (H_x - H_0)/x$. Since
$$
S_x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k\,(k+x)}
$$
is an absolutely convergent sum for $x>-1$ and $H_x = x\,S_x$, one deduces that $H_0 = 0$. Hence for any $x\neq 0$,
$$
\frac{H_x - H_0}{x} = \frac{x\,S_x - 0}{x} = S_x
$$
and it follows easily by taking the limit in this sum that $H'_0 = S_0 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ which is well-known to be equal to $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: More intuitive than my approach +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{H_x}x=\frac{\pi^2}6$$By L'Hopital's rule $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}H'(x)=H'(0)=\frac{\pi^2}6$$